# Import specific variables of an SAS file into R

Tags: r, database, import, sas, subset

I need to import a specific set of variables in a SAS file (.sas7bat) into R and not the whole file. Is there a way to do it ? So far I am actually creating a subset data set in SAS and then reading them into R. I don't want to do that. I would like to know if there is a way where I can tell R to read only the specific columns and their attributes.

Comment: Check out Hadley's "HAVEN" package he's currently developing. I've not used it, but intend to do so.  https://github.com/hadley/haven

Comment: It appears from the documentation that `read.ssd` from the `foreign` package may work if you have SAS installed on the same computer. See `library(foreign); ?read.ssd`